# PHP calls to external programs all fail with exit code 127

Tags: php, external-process

```
echo system("/usr/bin/whoami", $ret);
echo $ret;
```

PHP 4.3.9 on Apache 2.0.52, CentOS 4.5. Safe mode is off, I can run programs as the apache user account from the command line, but all programs run from PHP fail with exit code 127.

Comment: Did you try calling php mywhoami.php from CLI? You probably access it through the browser. For me it works both ways.

Comment: The shell (system() uses "/bin/sh -c ...") returns with exit code 127 when it can't find the command to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

- See if `/usr/bin/whoami` exists, and is executable (and readable, mode `xx5`) by anyone.
- See `php.ini` on `doc_root` and `user_dir`, if those are set they can limit what you can execute.
- If your Apache or PHP is chrooted, you need to put the application to execute into the chroot.
- If there's some other security system or RBAC running on the machine, see `dmesg` or log files in `/var/log/`.
- Don't forget to use `&$ret` instead of `$ret`.
- See PHP's `exec()` and `passthru()`, different functions might work for different situations.
- Know that there's a different `php.ini` for Apache, and a different one for cli use.